# What goes in to the parentheses of studentList.addStudent()?

Tags: java, linked-list

So I have a **GUI** class with the `addStudent()` method that is meant to call the method: `addStudent(Student aNewStudentObj)` of the **Manager** class to then create an object of the **Student** class using the information inputted by the user. This object is then meant to be stored in the Linked List that is in the **Manager** class.

My question is, what goes in the parentheses of the `addStudent()` method that is located in the **GUI** class if anything is meant to go in there?

I have literally tried everything that I could think of and now I am at the point of losing my hair so all help possible would very much be appreciated. Please.

I believe all required code is below but if you need the full **GUI** class, let me know. I also have a **Module** class but I don't think that will be necessary for this question.

`addStudent()` method from **GUI** class below

```
public void addStudent() {

        Manager studentList = new Manager();
        studentList.addStudent();  <-----------------  What goes in those brackets?
    }
```

**Student** class below

```
public class Student {

    private String firstName;
    private String surname;
    private String email;
    private int yearOfStudy;
    private int studentId;
    private Queue<Module> mods = new LinkedList<>();

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public int getYearOfStudy() {
        return yearOfStudy;
    }

    public int getStudentId() {
        return studentId;
    }

    public String print() {
        return "Student ID: " + studentId + "\n"
                + "First Name: " + firstName + "\n"
                + "Surname: " + surname + "\n"
                + "Email: " + email + "\n"
                + "Year of Study: " + yearOfStudy;
    }

    public void addModule(int id, String mCode, int mMark) {
        if (mods.size() == 4) {
            mods.remove();
        }

        Module module = new Module();
        mods.add(module);
    }

    //this method returns the module list of this student sorted by marks
    public String getModulesSortedByMarks(int id) {
        Object[] sortedMods;
        sortedMods = mods.toArray();

        Arrays.sort(sortedMods);

        String sortedModulesList = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < sortedMods.length; i++) {
            sortedModulesList = "\n" + ((Module) sortedMods[i]).print();
        }
        return sortedModulesList;

    }
}
```

**Manager** class below

```
public class Manager {

    List<Student> studs = new LinkedList<>();

    public void addStudent(Student aNewStudentObj) {

        studs.add(aNewStudentObj);
    }

    public void displayStudent(int studentId) {

        System.out.println(studs.get(studentId));
    }

    public void displayMarks(int studentId) {

        Student marks = new Student();
        marks.getModulesSortedByMarks(studentId);
    }

    public void deleteStudent(int studentId) {

        studs.remove(studentId);
    }

    public void displayAll() {

        for (Student student : studs) {
            student.print();
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"What goes in those brackets?"* an instance of `Student`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: What (if any) argument gets passed in to `studentList.addStudent()`?

A: That depends entirely on what parameters the `addStudent()` method of "studentList's` class takes.

In your case:

1. `studentList` is a `Manager` (poor name for either variable or class, but..)
2. `Manager.addStudent()` takes an object of class type `Student`.
3. You need to have an object of type `Student` available when you call `addStudent`.

One of your challenges in your code is that you currently have no way of giving a "Student" a name or student ID.  That's a problem.

Two solutions:

a) Create "setter" methods for name etc.

... and/or ...

b) Create a constructor that accepts name etc. as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do several things to make your code work.

From what I understand from your question, your `Manager` class maintains all data related to students.

You should have only one instance of `Manager` class. But your `addStudent` method of `GUI` class creates a new `Manager` instance every time it is called.

Next, you need a way to create an instance of `Student` class with the required values for the properties e.g. `firstname`, `surname` etc. You can create a constructor with all these arguments.

Finally, to answer the point in your question, you need to create an instance of `Student` and pass that to `addStudent` method of `Manager` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
private List<Student> studentList;

public void addStudent(Student student) {
        studentList.addStudent(student);  // <--  What goes in those brackets?
}

private Student student;
private List<Student> studentList;

public void addStudent() {
            studentList.addStudent(student);  // <--  What goes in those brackets?
    }
```

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Q: But how and where do we create a "student" object?  As written, the code will pass a "null" in to addStudent().

Comment: I think you solved it! Not getting any errors for now. Cheers Max

Comment: Yes, you are right, I wanted to explain him,what should be placed inside the brackets,

Comment: @A.Shah i changed my code, so you have a better solution. Your welcome, if i still helped you :).